# Cannot upcast string to tinyint pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a hive table that I'm trying to read like this,

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.yarn.queue", "my_yarn_queue")
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .getOrCreate()


sdf = spark.read.table('db_name.table_name')
```

I ended up with an AnalysisException that goes like this,

> AnalysisException: 'Cannot up cast table.`col_a` from string to
> col_a#8242: tinyint as it may truncate\n;'

I saw some solutions for reading a csv file in Scala. I don't think I can use that. I don't know the schema of the table and if I could get it somehow I'm not sure how to use it here to solve this error.

How to fix this error?

I'm on spark 2.3 if that helps.!

Based on the comment by @Someshwar Kale, I tried reading with a schema like this,

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
  StructField("col_a", StringType()),
])


sdf = spark.read.schema(schema).table("db_name.table")
```

Then I ended up with the Analysis Exception

> AnalysisException: 'User specified schema not supported with `table`;'

Comment: get the schema of hive table and try to put it like `spark.read.schema(<put your schema>).table(<table_name>)`

Comment: getting another AnalysisException now : `AnalysisException: 'User specified schema not supported with `table`;'`

Comment: can you put the schema of hive table in the description? it will help answerers

Comment: updated in the Q

Comment: Also can you put full stack trace